# Why is there an option to create a separate class library for interfaces with business modules?

Tags: wcsf

In wcsf, it is possible to make a business module with a separate class library just for interfaces, if I tick the relevant box/boxes.

What is the point in having a separate class library just for interfaces? Wouldn't this add unnecessary bloat to my project and create a high coupling between two class libraries? What would be wrong with storing the interfaces in the class library storing concrete classes?

Thanks.

Comment: Think of the word "separate" as having the phrase "a rat" in the middle of it.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The advantage to storing the interfaces in a separate class library is that it actually *decouples* the implementing and using class libraries. If the interfaces are with the concrete implementing classes, then you have

ImplementingClasses.dll <--- ClientClasses.dll

If you put the interfaces into a separate assembly, it's more like this:

ImplementingClasses.dll ---> Interfaces.dll <--- ClientClasses.dll

Notice how this removes the coupling between your client code and the implementation - this will allow your total application to use a configuration-based approach to locating the proper implementing classes.

Comment: can you expand more on "configuration-based approach"? from what i've seen of WCSF the underlying ObjectBuilder DI framework doesn't actually allow everything to be fully specified in config. Like container.RegisterTypeMapping()

Comment: That comment wasn't WCSF specific. It does apply, in general to architecture concerns, and other DI tools would allow you to be more flexible with that separation of classes & interfaces.